# Offset eCharts markLine label when two markLine labels overlap

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

When markLines exist very close together on yAxis, it is hard to read.
[image]

I have tried offsetting vertically with distance and padding but both don't seem to move the label in the vertical axis.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/isachenx/pen/ZEZbLXg

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line',
            markLine: {
        data: [
             {
            type: 'test',
            name: 'test',
            yAxis: 197,
            label: {
              backgroundColor: 'pink',
              distance: [20, 300],
              padding: [50,0,0,0]
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'average',
            name: 'Avg',
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
```